# I need to create a PDF file on the client side using GWT. How do I do that?

Tags: pdf, gwt, client-side, xls

This is based on [Can anyone tell me that is it possible to generate PDF files using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029238/can-anyone-tell-me-that-is-it-possible-to-generate-pdf-files-using-javascript)
For me, pdf and/or xls.

Also can I just create a single txt file using GWT because I know JavaScript doesn't have rights to do that client-side for security reasons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GWT is also using javascript on client side and if you want to create PDF on client, you must provide that PDF from server, for example from java-servlet.

Comment: I would have said that, too. But then I followed the linked question, and checked out the jsPDF library example: http://snapshotmedia.co.uk/blog/jspdf (Click on "Run Code") - it's amazing, but the PDF is actually created on the client side... (it uses either Flash or pure JS, depending on the browser).

Comment: then as @nacho3d answered may be JSNI will help to use jsPDF

Comment: yes but the thing is , it aint supporting 60% of browsers , and by that , i mean INTERNET EXPLORER.

Comment: IE is total fail :), then server side generating is only way to do that

Comment: yes but we gotta support the leading browser no matter how messy it is ... damnit. damnyou IE.
thanks anyway :D

Comment: I think that every developer have to evangelize the not use of IE in our clients.

Comment: in out products Google Chome is "technical requirement" :]

Comment: Hey chaps, I'm the author of jsPDF, yep it does work in IE when used with downloadify. There's an example in the github repo

Answer (score 0):

You can do as ultor said, call a RPC create a PDF and send it to the browser.

Or you can use JSNI ( http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2008/07/getting-to-really-know-gwt-part-1-jsni.html ) to call JS native methods, and in this way you can call the methods of jsPDF from your GWT code.