# Angular js Table Export to Pdf

Tags: angularjs, export-to-pdf

Anyone please tell how to perform exporting of angularjs table to PDF document?
I exported my table to xls format, it works fine., but I couldn't do the table pdf export. Please help.

Comment: Edit your question, instead of writing comment

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can anyone tell me that is it possible to generate PDF files using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029238/can-anyone-tell-me-that-is-it-possible-to-generate-pdf-files-using-javascript)